# 1 microsoft second = 0.00001157407407

Tags: excel

I was writing a routine to read from an Excel spreadsheet.

I have just discovered thro that MS Excel spreadsheet that

1 microsoft second = 0.00001157407407

```
1/1/1900 0:00:01.000    1.000011574
1/2/1900 0:00:02.000    2.000023148
```

Why?

Why not 0.00001, or some rounder number?

What is the significance of 0.00001157407407?

Binary value = 0.00000000000000001100001000101110

Comment: How did you get to this number?

Comment: How did you determine the binary value.  Is that the floating point value?  It has two parts, right?

Comment: You get what you measure, and it's probably some rounding ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Excel, each day is represented by 1.0, with a value of 1.0 being equal to January 1st, 1900 (ie: it's effectively the days since 12/31/1899, plus one if you're after Feb 1900).

This works out to each second being the number you posted, which is effectively `1 day / (24 * 60 * 60)` or `1 / 86400 == 0.00001157407407`.

Comment: @pnuts Good point about the 1 day out issue with Feb.  I detailed the 1 day -> timings, though, in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Because 1 day is recorded in excel as `1`.  `1 / (24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds) = 1 / 86400 = 1.157407407407407e-5`

Answer (score -3):

Never mind ....

```
24 x 60 x 60 = 86400
0.00001157407407 x 86400 = 1
```

The significance of 0.00001157407407 is that it is the the fractional value of a second to a day.

Comment: Actually that should be the opposite. 0.00001.... is the number of days in a second.

Comment: Corrected the logic.